# How to import ActionBarSherlock in android SDK version 23

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to implement the Sherlock ActionBar in Android Studios, however as I am new to Android studios I do not understand what I need to put into the build.gradle file dependencies section in Android in order for this to be imported.

I am currently using the lastest version of Andriod Studos with SDK version 23. Please help.

Someone has advised me that this is no longer available in Andriod Studios so how can I do the below then.

So how can I do This then. public class MenuActivity extends SherlockActivity implements

public class MenuActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener,

Comment: ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated for ~15 months. It is no longer being maintained, with no updates for ~3 years. IMHO, no new projects should be using it. Either use the official `appcompat-v7` backport, or use the native action bar.

Comment: So I cant use Sherlock anymore.

Comment: So how can I do This then. public class MenuActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener,

Answer (score 0):

Since ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated, you can use the Toolbar Class from the `appcompat-v7` library.

1. On your gradle file, add:

   dependencies {

   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

   }
2. For your layout, you can use something like this:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:elevation="0dp"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
       local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   ```
3. On Your MenuActivity.java:

   ```
   public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

           final mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   }
   ```
4. On your styles.xml file:

> ```
> <resources>
> <!-- Base application theme. -->
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme">
>     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
> </style>
>
> <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
> </style>
> </resources>
> ```